# html in d3.js text tag

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, text

I have an axis:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .style("text-anchor", "center")
    .text("pdot [&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]");
```

but apparently the label is rendered 'as is'. Changing the last line to

```
.html("pdot [&times;10<sup>-15</sup> ss<sup>-1</sup>]");
```

still does not produce what I want. How to make `text` tag display processed html? I'm looking for general solution that will allow me to put any html code into the label. However, the best would be the way to use LaTeX. Is it possible? How?

Comment: do you have a simple jsfiddle of what youre trying to do ?

Comment: Use a `foreignObject`: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037

Comment: It's not that .html() won't work, its that <sup> tags don't work with it. Use the foreginObject solution as Lars mentions.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks, it worked. The working example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/kzyt9L1w/1/ Please consider submitting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `foreignObject` for that, see e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037.